# Python pandas dataframe sort_values does not work for second term

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe contains sales data

```
Order ID Order Date Order Priority  Order Quantity     Sales  
  928.0   1/1/2009           High            32.0    180.36 
10369.0   1/2/2009            Low            43.0  4,083.19
10144.0   1/2/2009       Critical            16.0    137.63             
32323.0   1/1/2009  Not Specified             9.0    872.48          
48353.0   1/2/2009       Critical             3.0    124.81         
51008.0   1/3/2009       Critical            15.0     85.56       
26756.0   1/2/2009       Critical            43.0     614.8         
18144.0   1/2/2009            Low             4.0  1,239.06         
22912.0   1/2/2009            Low            32.0  4,902.38
...
```

I would like to sort values by Date (oldest to newest) and Sales (largest to smallest). I wrote this code in PyCharm Edu 3.5.1 (python 2.7):

```
df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', header=0)
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'])
df = df.sort_values(by=['Order Date', 'Sales'], ascending=[True, False])
print df.head(10)
```

Output:

```
    Order ID Order Date Order Priority  Order Quantity      Sales  
    32323.0 2009-01-01  Not Specified             9.0     872.48          
    928.0   2009-01-01           High            32.0     180.36          
    26756.0 2009-01-02       Critical            43.0      614.8         
    22912.0 2009-01-02            Low            32.0   4,902.38         
    10369.0 2009-01-02            Low            43.0   4,083.19          
    10144.0 2009-01-02       Critical            16.0     137.63          
    48353.0 2009-01-02       Critical             3.0     124.81          
    18144.0 2009-01-02            Low             4.0   1,239.06         
    29376.0 2009-01-03  Not Specified             4.0     896.49
...
```

The 'Order Date' column sorted properly but the 'Sales' column is not sorted as expected. It seems PyCharm ignores the value with , for the 1000 separator. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It seems need `df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', header=0, thousands=',')` for convert column `Sales` to `float`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with parameter `thousands` for remove `,` in floats and `parse_dates` for convert column to datetime, because values of column `Sales` was read as `string`s:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sales.csv', thousands=',', parse_dates=['Order Date'])
print (df)
   Order ID Order Date Order Priority  Order Quantity    Sales
0     928.0 2009-01-01           High            32.0   180.36
1   10369.0 2009-01-02            Low            43.0  4083.19
2   10144.0 2009-01-02       Critical            16.0   137.63
3   32323.0 2009-01-01  Not Specified             9.0   872.48
4   48353.0 2009-01-02       Critical             3.0   124.81
5   51008.0 2009-01-03       Critical            15.0    85.56
6   26756.0 2009-01-02       Critical            43.0   614.80
7   18144.0 2009-01-02            Low             4.0  1239.06
8   22912.0 2009-01-02            Low            32.0  4902.38

df = df.sort_values(by=['Order Date', 'Sales'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
   Order ID Order Date Order Priority  Order Quantity    Sales
3   32323.0 2009-01-01  Not Specified             9.0   872.48
0     928.0 2009-01-01           High            32.0   180.36
8   22912.0 2009-01-02            Low            32.0  4902.38
1   10369.0 2009-01-02            Low            43.0  4083.19
7   18144.0 2009-01-02            Low             4.0  1239.06
6   26756.0 2009-01-02       Critical            43.0   614.80
2   10144.0 2009-01-02       Critical            16.0   137.63
4   48353.0 2009-01-02       Critical             3.0   124.81
5   51008.0 2009-01-03       Critical            15.0    85.56
```

Another solution is use [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) or [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df['Order Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Date'])
df['Sales'] = df['Sales'].replace(',', '', regex=True).astype(float)
#if astype does not work because bad data
#df['Sales'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Sales'].replace(',', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
df = df.sort_values(by=['Order Date', 'Sales'], ascending=[True, False])
print (df)
   Order ID Order Date Order Priority  Order Quantity    Sales
3   32323.0 2009-01-01  Not Specified             9.0   872.48
0     928.0 2009-01-01           High            32.0   180.36
8   22912.0 2009-01-02            Low            32.0  4902.38
1   10369.0 2009-01-02            Low            43.0  4083.19
7   18144.0 2009-01-02            Low             4.0  1239.06
6   26756.0 2009-01-02       Critical            43.0   614.80
2   10144.0 2009-01-02       Critical            16.0   137.63
4   48353.0 2009-01-02       Critical             3.0   124.81
5   51008.0 2009-01-03       Critical            15.0    85.56
```